# How can id access an array of ids from jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here the snippet of code

```
var input_form =["first_text","middle_text","last_text","suffix_text","title_text","url_text","day_pnum","mon_pselect","year_pnum","day_anum","mon_aselect","year_anum"];
```

where "first_text","middle_text",... refers to the different ids in my html

i can access it via `document.getElementById(input_form[i])`, (within for loop)
but i have to use jquery, so whats wrong when i write the above code in jquery as `$(input_form[i])` to get the same result

Comment: jQuery uses the same syntax as CSS selectors ... an id is `#id` ... so ... `$('#'+input_form[i]) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since jQuery are query selectors (or CSS selectors), for id you need to prefix with `#`. So use this way:

```
$("#" + input_form[i])
```

Comment: thnx a ton brother

Answer (score 0):

You missed the # selector, try with this:

```
$("#" + input_form[i])
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < input_form.length; i++) {
 var $el = $('#' + input_form[i]);
}
```

$el would give u the element's jquery reference

Answer (score 0):

For id selectors, jQuery uses the JavaScript function `document.getElementById()`, which is extremely efficient. When another selector is attached to the id selector as `#`.you can use like below:

```
$("#" + input_form[i])
```

or

```
$('[id=input_form[i]]')
```

For more information check [here](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your needs, you can also select all of your input's as one jQuery object, is such case you can for e.g. call `.val('')` to clean all of them. 
Example:

```
var input_form =["first_text","middle_text","last_text","suffix_text","title_text","url_text","day_pnum","mon_pselect","year_pnum","day_anum","mon_aselect","year_anum"];
var inputs_selector = input_form.map(s => "#" + s).join(",");
// reset all values
$(inputs_selector).val('');
```